# MariaDB 10.0.25 installs without configuration

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu, password

While trying to install `MariaDB` on `Ubuntu 15.10`, I issue command

```
$ sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

and it outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-10.0 
  mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-server-10.0 
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  mailx mariadb-test tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libmysqlclient18 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-client-10.0 
  mariadb-client-core-10.0 mariadb-common mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.0 
  mariadb-server-core-10.0 mysql-common
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/11.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 122 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

At the end the installation of packages are completed and the service `mysql` get installed. But, I never get a prompt/wizard for setting `root` credentials and other configuration. And later I'm not able to connect to the service

```
$ mysql -u -root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user '-root'@'localhost'
```

Not able to understand what is going wrong.

**UPDATE**
What's more intriguing is the following

```
$ sudo mysqladmin -u root password <myPassword>
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: <myPassword>
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

I'm completely puzzled.

Comment: Was there any instance of MySQL/Mariadb/Percona installed? If it was removed with only `apt-get remove` (and not with `apt-get purge`), `apt` removes just a package, leaving everything (data and configuration files) else. Read more [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/562964/difference-between-apt-get-remove-y-and-apt-get-purge-y). What repository are You using: Ubuntu or Maria (my guess is Ubuntu's default)?

Comment: **1** Yes, I found out I had an old installation and as you said, I had purged it.
**2** Yes, I am using Ubuntu's default repository. But shouldn't it be providing `mariadb` as per [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mariadb-10.0)

Comment: And You've tried instaling it again after purging "leftovers"? With what result (same one)?

Comment: Yes. Not only that I went ahead and deleted contents under `/etc/mysql` to ensure nothing stays.

Comment: That will sound little windowish, but try purging everything related with MariaDB. Had similar issue when I've forgot my root password for some private testing instance.
So try `sudo apt-get purge mariadb*` if possible. Then reinstall packages once again.

Comment: Not only `sudo apt-get purge mariadb*` I have also done `sudo apt-get purge mysql*`. I have gone through all the suggestions across various portals. Only then was I forced to ask this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45033/discussion-between-marcin-s-and-soufrk).

Answer (score 1):

It appears You had some MySQL/MariaDB/Percona instance previously installed, and some of data and config files were left in Your OS.

The way that worked for me on that case (`Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS` with `MariaDB 10.0` installed), with forgotten Maria's root password, was:

- purging everything: `sudo apt-get purge mariadb*`
- reboot; it didn't work without it, probably some related service running in background, locking some files from being purged: `sudo reboot -h now`
- installing database once again: `sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`

Of course this was possible only on private dev machine, without any important data.

Comment: Yes, already. Even so the problem persists.

Comment: Post updated, according to positive results of our chat.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trial and error finally dropped installing on 15.10 and went ahead with 1604 instead,

- **FACT**: I had `mysql-server` installed long earlier, which as per [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-server), I'm guessing was ver 5.6
- **FACT**: I had Wily 15.10 32 bit installed.
- Now, as per [this](https://downloads.mariadb.org/), **MySQL-5.6** + **MariaDB-5.5 backported** = **MariaDB-10.0 GA**

  - Given that, **MariaDB-5.5** = **MySQL-5.5** + **MariaDB-5.3**
- Package `mariadb-server 10.0.25-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 (i386 binary)` depends on [mariadb-server-10.0 (>= 10.0.25-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/amd64/mariadb-server-10.0) and is only available for 15.04 with `amd64`, which I don't understand what it's supposed to mean
- **CONCLUSION**: Wily(15.04) started with MySQL 5.6, and right then MariaDB decided to fork and provide it's own distribution. Wily got upgraded to 15.10 but MariaDB hangs right in there in air.
- **ACTION**: Installed MaraDB in Xenial(16.04) 64 bit, and it works fine.